# Tagged traffic throught FreeBSD server

Tags: networking, freebsd, vlan

i have a cable from provider with two VLANs on it, VLAN1 for internet and VLAN50 for VoIP. I need to take VLAN50 to my 192.168.0.2 server (PBX Panasonic TDE-600) on schema so it can connect to SIP server through VLAN50

I made two trunk tagged ports on upper switch (one leads to provider and other leads to freebsd router) and on lower switch tagged trunk port leading to router and access port leading to 192.168.0.2 server (PBX)

But i don't know how to bring tagged traffic of VLAN50 through my FreeBSD server(router). Help me please. Thanks.

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3dOw.png)

Answer (score 3):

Per the [FreeBSD handbook on VLANs](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-vlan.html) you can simply create subinterfaces in */etc/rc.conf*):

```
vlans_em0="50"
ifconfig_em0="inet 192.0.2.1/24"
ifconfig_em0_50="inet 198.51.100.23/24"
```

This assume VLAN 1 comes in untagged while VLAN 50 is tagged.

Next you will need to create a bridge on the FreeBSD server/router/firewall and bridge the traffic between `em0.50` and `em1`.

Comment: You mean bridge between what interfaces? If i put in bridge em0 or em1 my freebsd server will stop working as default gateway for my local subnet, no?

Comment: I made more detailed scheme [here](https://imgur.com/a/XtmY6za) No need to do anything with Vlan1, it's default, i need to connect to SIP server 11.11.11.1 which in VLAN50, provider gives me 3 ip from this subnet - 11.11.11.10-13/24. I need that my PBX could connect to 11.11.11.1 and i could connect to PBX from local subnet.